# Graphene Mutation error, fields must be a mapping (dict / OrderedDict)

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, graphene-python

I'm starting to wrap my head around with GraphQl/Graphene. I'm building a schema connected to a MongoDB. All seems to work so far except mutations. I've been following the example [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/examples/complex_example.py) and [here](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/mutations/) without luck. Can someone point me towards what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import graphene

class GeoInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    lat = graphene.Float(required=True)
    lng = graphene.Float(required=True)

    @property
    def latlng(self):
        return "({},{})".format(self.lat, self.lng)


class Address(graphene.ObjectType):
    latlng = graphene.String()


class CreateAddress(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        geo = GeoInput(required=True)

    Output = Address

    def mutate(self, info, geo):
        return Address(latlng=geo.latlng)


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_address = CreateAddress.Field()


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    address = graphene.Field(Address, geo=GeoInput(required=True))
    def resolve_address(self, info, geo):
        return Address(latlng=geo.latlng)

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

The code above generates this error:

> AssertionError: CreateAddress fields must be a mapping (dict /
>   OrderedDict) with field names as keys or a function which returns such
>   a mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the version of graphene I had installed, installing graphene 2.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the import.
I've had same issue when I used:

```py
from graphene import ObjectType
```

I've found how to import it properly in next example from [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#hello-graphql-schema-and-object-types). Here it is:

```py
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had declared all of my fields incorrectly. This is my Type:

```
class EventDateRangeType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = EventDateRange
        fields = ('start', 'end')
```

But my Model was:

```
class EventDateRange(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

So `start` & `end` don't match `start_time` & `end_time`. Making them the same fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your mutation:

```
Output = Address
```

Should be a graphene object:

```
Output = graphene.Field(Address)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error for a class that inherited from "InputObjectType". The solution was to import "InputObjectType" from `graphene` instead of from `graphql.type.tests.test_definition` (don't know why it was imported from that library in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

It can even happen if no output is specified in `graphene.Mutation` inheriting class.
But that is not case for DevilWarior.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30894858)